# convert void* hex to decimal int

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, hex, converters

Hello I need your help to convert void* (hex number) to decimal number. I use sqlite3 in my code and the callback function give me a &data that contains number of row. the problem is: I need to save  &data (hex number) as int. maybe there is another way to do this but I try to convert the &data hex to decimal int and the issue is to convert the void*. I try to convert the void* to int but the Running time problem to get the pointer. I will be happy if you help me do the conversion.
Thanks.

some code -

```
void* data = nullptr;
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, str.data(), callback, &data, &zErrMsg);
int id = 0;

if (data != nullptr)
{
    int dataa = *((int *)data); // run time error
    istringstream(dataa) >> std::hex >> id; \\ istringstream can't convert void* // NEED CHANGE
}
return id;
```

callback function -

```
if (argc == 0) {
     user_exist = false; return 0;
}
else {
    user_exist = true; 
    if (notUsed != NULL) {
        cout << argv[0] << endl;
       ((int)notUsed) = atoi(argv[0]); 
    }
 }
return 0;
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say `void *data` is a hex number? Do you mean it is a NUL-terminated C string containing a number as hex digits? Do you mean it is binary data, like any `int` variable? Or something else? Also, the `istringstream` comment makes no sense, do you have a typo in that line? Also, what "run time error" do you get for the first problem line, and what exact compiler error you get for the 2nd problem line?

Comment: @hyde when I print data like this "cout << data" I get for example 000000B (in hex 11) now I wont to convert this to int 11 and the "run time error happening when I try to convert data to int and I get the message "Unhandled exception at 0x00E5A9FF in A.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000B."

Comment: Checking https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html I would say, problem is in the `callback` function. 0xB is clearly invalid pointer value in a program like this, so most likely `callback` does something funny.

Comment: @hyde this is my callback I think its OK  the value in data is B and B = 11 
and this is the callback function - 

 if (argc == 0)
 {
  user_exist = false;
  return 0;
 }
 else
 {
  user_exist = true;
  if (notUsed != NULL)
  {
   cout << argv[0] << endl;
   *((int*)notUsed) = atoi(argv[0]);
  }
 }
 return 0;

Comment: Please edit the callback code into your question, not as a comment. `((int)notUsed) = atoi(argv[0]);` This just assigns to the local variable `notUsed` (which is a misnomer); it doesn't do anything to `data`. You probably meant `int data;` and `*((int*)notUsed) = atoi(argv[0]);`

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I add the callback to the question, But I don't understand what I need to do to fix the problem. Do you have some options to do this ? Thanks

Comment: @user3742037: Your question is misleading, because there is no single answer. `void*` means "a pointer, but how you interpret it should be specified by the source". In this case, the source is SQLite. Since you clearly seem to be struggling with basic concepts such as decimal versus hexadecimal, dealing with `void*` is probably a bit too advanced.

Answer (score 0):

`sqlite3_exec()` is useful only when you can actually handle the data in the callback.
In practice, you should normally use the [sqlite3_prepare_v2()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html)/[sqlite3_step()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html)/[sqlite3_finalize()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html) functions to read data:

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT ...", -1, &stmt, NULL);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    print("error: ", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return -1;
}
rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
if (rc != SQLITE_ROW && rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
    print("error: ", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
} else {
    user_exist = rc == SQLITE_ROW;
}
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

(For most other queries, you would call the [sqlite3_column_*() functions](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) to read the actual values, as long as you get `SQLITE_ROW`.)